# Missing option "Upload Photo or Video" at iOS fileupload

Tags: javascript, iphone, file-upload, camera, dropzone.js

I'm wondering about my iPhone because I can't find a way to get a feature back which was available until yesterday.

I've made a Fileupload using dropzone.js and if I visit their website all options I expect are available (Upload Photo or Video - to directly upload a taken image).

See image below:

[image]

But if I'm in my webapp and do also a tap on dropzone area only my photo album is opened and I can't choose between album or camera.

Can't find a solution for my problem.

What could be the reason for that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a wrong defined setting option in dropzone.js

Previously I used:

```
$("#dropImage").dropzone({
                  url: "/upload-wp",
                  paramName: "file",
                  maxFiles: 10
                });
```

And If maxFiles is higher than 1 the camera selection won't appear.

```
    $("#dropImage").dropzone({
                  url: "/upload-wp",
                  paramName: "file",
                  maxFiles: 1 // <- solved the problem
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just give you idea.

I Hope this will help.

go to your dropzone.js and look the input. or

remove the if condition.

> if (_this.options.acceptedFiles != null) {
>
> ```
>         _this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("accept", _this.options.acceptedFiles);
>        }
> ```

replace to

> _this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("accept", "image/gif|image/jpeg|image/png");

thanks :D